# Images stored in Azure Blob don't cache in Browser

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, blob

I have set the cache-property to "max-age=3600, must-revalidate" when uploading. Looking at the browser developer tool, the network tab, I can see that the header is correct and the cache property is sett.
But still the Photos get fetched from the Azure blob storage every time with 200OK response.

The way I upload is as follows:
-Photo uploaded by user
-GUID added to name of photo and saved to Azure SQL database with user info.
-Blob Reference created using Azure library in C#
-Cache properties set and saved after uploading

```
    var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + fileName;
    var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueFileName);
    using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
    newBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream).Wait();
    newBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=3600, must-revalidate";
    newBlob.SetPropertiesAsync().Wait();
```

Blob is fetch by using an URI + SAS Token
I get the name from the SQL database, Look it up in azure Blob then getting the URI and Adding The SAS to give the Client access to the Blob.

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                });
                var blobUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken;
```

I found that every time a new SAS is created the image is treated as new version. And I do create a new SAS for every request to create a link that the client use to download image. How can I bypass this behavior. Should I make the container accessible by public for read with no SAS used?

Answer (score 0):

The `cache control` should work if using blob with SAS token.

If you're using a browser(like Chrome) to visit the blob with SAS token, please make sure you DON'T select the checkbox of "Disable cache" in Develop tool. I can see it uses cache at my side, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Of course I've done that! And I can see the cache control saved. still not working. I have "append-version sett to true on the Rezor page too"

Comment: One thing that may give a hint! every time a new request is made to get the image, a new SAS is created and added. And I have  asp-append-version="true" in Razor page. I suspect some missed up versioning going on with this recipe. I will test more, but I thought to share with you. May be you got an idea.

Comment: @Giss, if you add asp-append-version="true", the blob url with different sastoken should be treated as a different version. That may be the root cause.

Comment: alright, so here is the thing. The SAS token if changed is treated as new version, this what I found. But I use the SAS to create a link to the blob so it is downloaded directly to the client. But then with every request a new SAS is created and so the cache fails. Unless the same SAS token is used with the client with every request. I could of course stream Read the blob and send it with the request. But that doesn't sound idle. So what's the work around?

Comment: @Giss, we can create a container-level sastoken, and assign it to each blob with each request.

Comment: @Giss, or you can create a `stored access policy`, for each request, you can append the `stored access policy` to the blob. Hope it helps:).

Comment: I will check that out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Giss, please let me know if you need any help:).

Comment: Thanks man! I still have not take a look at it. Will let you know!